# Как сократить отображаемое число в PHP?

Tags: php

Допустим имею данное число: 3985.
Как мне её превратить в данную строку: 3,9К ?

Comment: Доя этого есть функция number_format. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Comment: Получается 3,985 а мне нужно еще как-то обрезать что-бы было 3,9

Comment: round((ваше_число/1000),1).'K'

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 9):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию:

```
function formatNumber(int $int): String
{
    $k = (int) log($int, 1000);
    $float = round($int / pow(1000, $k), 1);
    $letters = ['К', 'М', 'Млрд'];

    return $float . ($letters[--$k] ?? '');
}
```

Примеры использования:

```
echo formatNumber(7); // 7
echo formatNumber(78); // 78
echo formatNumber(789); // 789
echo formatNumber(7899); // 7.9К
echo formatNumber(78991); // 79К
echo formatNumber(789919); // 789.9К
echo formatNumber(7899191); // 7.9М
echo formatNumber(78991911); // 79М
echo formatNumber(789919119); // 789.9М
echo formatNumber(7899191191); // 7.9Млрд
echo formatNumber(78991911910); // 79Млрд
```

Comment: `$letters = [, 'k', ...]` первый элемент пустым если оставить, то никакие `--` не нужны будут.

Answer (score 3):

Решение:

```
function views($value)
{
    if ($value >= 1000) return round($value / 1000, 1).'K';
    else return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант в коллекцию:

```
function getShortNumber($number)
{
    $number = (float)$number;

    if ($number <= 999 and $number >= -999)  {
        $format = number_format($number, 0, '.', '');
    } else if($number <= 999999 and $number >= -999999){
        $format = number_format($number/1e3, 1, '.', '') + 0 .'k'; // (к) кило-, kilo-
    } else if($number <= 999999999 and $number >= -999999999){
        $format = number_format($number/1e6, 2, '.', '') + 0 .'M'; // (М) мега-, mega-
    } else {
        $format = number_format($number/1e9, 2, '.', '') + 0 .'G'; // (Г) гига-, giga-
    }
    return $format;
}
```

Можно задать количество символов после запятой.

**Тысяча** —  кило-, kilo-.
**Миллион** —  мега-, mega-.
**Миллиард** (биллион) — гига-, giga-.
**Триллион** —  тера-, tera-.
**Квадриллион** —  пета-, peta-.
**Квинтиллион** — экса-, exa-.
**Секстиллион** — зетта-, zetta-.
**Септиллион** —  иотта-, yotta-.